# how to get the values from keys on soap xml

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have an soap xml but I have a challenge getting the values without using indexes.

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result xmlns="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/result">
  <ResultType>0</ResultType>
  <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
  <ResultDesc>The service request is processed successfully.</ResultDesc>
  <ResultParameters>
    <ResultParameter>
      <Key>TransactionAmount</Key>
      <Value>500</Value>
    </ResultParameter>
    <ResultParameter>
      <Key>TransactionReceipt</Key>
      <Value>LIB967VYGF</Value>
    </ResultParameter>
  </ResultParameters>
  <ReferenceData>
    <ReferenceItem>
      <Key>QueueTimeoutURL</Key>
      <Value>https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/NotificationService?wsdl</Value>
    </ReferenceItem>
  </ReferenceData>
</Result>
```

To get the values, I parse the xml;

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($response) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

Then get the values from the object;

```
$ResultType=$xml->ResultType;
$ResultCode=$xml->ResultCode;
$ResultDesc= $xml->ResultDesc;
```

The rest on the `<ResultParameters>` tags are the challenge.

I would want to to get them in any other safe way apart from their indexes as this could change. This would fail if the `<ResultParameter>` are interchanged.

This is what I do to get them;

```
$Amount= $xml->ResultParameters->ResultParameter[0]->Value;
$TransactionReceipt= $xml->ResultParameters->ResultParameter[1]->Value;
```

Anyone share the secret here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XPath you can find the `<Key>TransactionAmount</Key>` entry and track the value from there.  But being XPath, the default namespace sort of gets in the way.  So each element has to be referenced by prefix:elementName.

So first register the namespace (giving it some easier prefix) and then retrieve it using the `<Key>` as the start point.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($response);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("default", "http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/result");

$amount= (string)$xml->xpath("//default:Key[text()='TransactionAmount']/../default:Value/text()")[0];

echo "Amount=".$amount.PHP_EOL;
```

As `->xpath` returns an array - you just take the first item from it.  But this is still an object, so the cast to string makes it something more useful (in general).

Do a similar thing for any of the other values you need.